# How to insert data inside Mongo object through Python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Inside the *expenses* collection I have this Json:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5ad0870d2602ff20497b71b8"),
"Hotel" : {}
}
```

I want to insert a document or another object if possible inside `Hotel` using Python.

My Python code:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client['db']
collection_expenses = db ['expenses']
#insert
d = int(input('Insert how many days did you stay?: '))
founded_expenses = collection_expenses.insert_one({'days':d})
```

The code above inserts the document inside the collection. What should I change to add the days inside de Hotel object?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `insert_one`, you may want to take a look to the `save` method, which is a little bit more permissive.

Admitting your document is already created in the collection:

```
[...]
expenses = db['expenses']

# Find your document
expense = expense.find_one({})

expense["Hotel"] = { "days": d }

# This will either update or save as a new document the expense dict,
# depending on whether or not it already has an _id parameter
expenses.save(expense)
```

Knowing that `find_one` will return you `None` if no such document exist, you may want to upsert a document. You can thus easily do so with `save`.